# File names have a `hidden' m character prepended

Tags: python, terminal, os.system

I have a simple python script which produces some data in a Neutron star mode. I use it to automate file names so I don't later forget the inputs. The script succesfully saves the file as

```
some_parameters.txt
```

but when I then list the files in terminal I see

```
msome_parameters.txt
```

The file name without the "m" is still valid and trying to call the file with the m returns

```
$ ls m*
No such file or directory
```

So I think the "m" has some special meaning of which numerous google searches do not yields answers. While I can carry on without worrying, I would like to know the cause. Here is how I create the file in python

```
# chi,epsI etc are all floats. Make a string for the file name
file_name = "chi_%s_epsI_%s_epsA_%s_omega0_%s_eta_%s.txt" % (chi,epsI,epsA,omega0,eta) 

# a.out is the compiled c file which outputs data
os.system("./a.out >  %s" % (file_name) )
```

Any advise would be much appreciated, usually I can find the answer already posted in the stackoverflow but this time I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file with some special characters in the name which is confusing the terminal output. What happens if you do `ls -l` or (if possible) use a graphical file manager - basically, find a different way of listing the files so you can see what's going on. Another possibility would be to do `ls > some_other_filename` and then look at the file with a hex editor.

Comment: Hello Phillip, thanks for taking your time to look at this.

From Nautilus (graphical file manager) I see the normal files with no "m". From `ls -l` I get the following

`[Averaged_ODEs]$ ls -l`

`total 36`

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 ga7g08 ga7g08  7664 Apr  9 16:25 maveraged_chi_30.0.txt`

Sorry for the formatting I can't get line breaks. The file name should be averaged_chi_30.0.txt.

Comment: Dear Phillip, I am so sorry for wasting your time. Having thought about your comment I realised I had edited my bashrc in terminal to colour `.txt` files orange. But had done this incorrectly causing this error. I do apologies and thank you again.